# What type of connector for RS-485 is this?

Tags: identification, connector

I have an Actor from 'Warema' ([datasheet](https://warema.com/media/890350_h.pdf)). I need to connect my control unit to it.  The RS485 bus needs the following connectors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was unable to find the right connector in online markets (RS, Mouser.) The company also does not want to share this information with me.

Is this a standard connector or is it custom made?

Comment: _”The company also does not want to share this information with me.”_ That does not inspire confidence.

Comment: Is there any writing or a logo on those connectors?  If possible to share a close-up image, please do.

Comment: Looks custom to me.

Comment: *”The company also does not want to share this information with me.”* That's odd, as their diagram shows daisy chaining the device (to next bus device), including that specific connection.  Is this a part you only get when you buy it new?

Comment: So given the answer, did you specifically asked the manufacturer about what connector they use on their product, or how to connect RS485 cables to the product - as there is a difference. It would be quite understandable that they don't want to disclose which connector they bought from which manufacturer as that might be a trade secret, maybe because they think you are trying to repair the product by yourself or clone the product.

Comment: Yes I did, but in their defense: They are a company for shading, insulation and central air solutions. The electronics (and the logic elements) are probably specially build for them by an external partner (the PCB inside has a stamp from a big electronics company). I think they were not able to provide the answer rather than unwilling.

Comment: Do note, that if shielded cable is used, only *one* end of the shield is to be grounded.

Comment: Yes. Standard buses need a termination. This is also noted in the manual.

Comment: Off-topic, you need to peel those cables much shorter. There shouldn't be any exposed metal like that, or you are likely to get accidental shorts. Do the same with multi-strand wires and you _will_ get accidental shorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those connectors are known as KNX or EIB connectors. They are quite popular in smart home applications.

They allow the user to insert the cable directly inside the connector:

[image]

*Img Src: KNX Association - KNX Basics Course*

There's no matching connector or receptacle for KNX/EIB connectors. Just insert the stripped cable inside.

Comment: Now that I know the answer it makes sense. I was unsure just to 'force' the cable into the connector.Thanks for the info.